# Cannot create a new scala project in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-assembly

I cannot create a new scala project in IntelliJ. It does not recognize the scala syntax. For example, in the below code

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
)
```

It does not recognize the word Seq. THis is my assembly file

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.12.0")
```

My build.properties is

```
sbt.version=0.13.16
```

Comment: You would need scala language jar in your intellij libraries.

Comment: Thanks @RameshMaharjan, can you please tell me how I can do it? The reason I ask is, as per this link, https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2010/09/02/project-configuration-explained/ I need to add the scala-library.jar. But my Intellij contains only Python. BTW, the issue is resolved by deleting this one and creating a new one. That, clearly is not the correct way to do it. So it will be nice to know why this happened.

Comment: sbt had to download it automatically. There might have been some issue while downloading then

Comment: @Srinivas Have you added scala and sbt plugins to your IDE?

Comment: @AkashTantri - Thanks for looking at this. I did not, what are scala plugins? I tried to Add Framework Support for scala and was surprised that none other than Python is present.

Comment: @Srinivas Open IntelliJ IDE -> File -> Settings -> Plugins 
Install Scala and sbt plugin

Comment: don't add the sbt plugin, that one is obsolete for newer versions of IntelliJ :)

Comment: Does adding Scala plugin help?

Comment: @y.bedrov This is not the first scala project I have created in this machine, so I think the plugin need not be added (I am very new to Intellij so I can be completely wrong, so please bear with me). But I am looking at Spark Streaming, I need to create a project in my own windows machine. I will try creating one tonight and post here. Thanks everyone for showing interest in this help

Comment: @Srinivas any updates??

Comment: @AkashTantri it still did not work.